# Csv file into seperate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.7

I need to separate few csv files to incoming and outgoing traffic based on column values. This code doesn't give any output nor any error.

if source == ac:37:43:9b:92:24 && Receiver address == 8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a then those rows need to get written to .out.csv files.

if Transmitter address == 8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a && Destination== ac:37:43:9b:92:24 then those rows need to get written into .in.csv files.

```
import csv
import os
import subprocess

startdir = '.'   
outdir = '.'
suffix = '.csv'

def decode_to_file(cmd, in_file, new_suffix):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    filename = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + new_suffix
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))
    for line_bytes in proc.stdout:
        line_str = line_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        csv_writer.writerow(line_str.strip().split(','))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
    for name in files:
        if not name.endswith(suffix):
            continue
        in_file = os.path.join(root, name)

        decode_to_file(
            cmd= [source== "ac:37:43:9b:92:24" && Receiver address== "8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a"],
            in_file=in_file,
            new_suffix='.out.csv'
        )
        decode_to_file(
            cmd= [Transmitter address == "8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a" && Destination== "ac:37:43:9b:92:24"],
            in_file=in_file,
            new_suffix='.in.csv'
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Subprocess.Popen is for running bash commands, not python. And you can't put an if statement in a list like that, it gets executed once on the line where you define it. You could define a small function and pass it in as `cmd` and also, the MAC address should be a string by wrapping it in quotes. Finally, in Python we name things using `lower_case_with_ubderscores`, so fileName should be file_name or simply filename.

Comment: @Boris Thanks, I used quotes for the MAC address and changed the fileName as suggested. But still it is not working. I am new to programming, Sorry, I am not sure how to define a function ans pass it in as cmd. could you please tel me how can I do this please. Thanks

Comment: Update you question with your new code. But it won't work because you're using subprocess.Popen incorrectly. The right way is to open the file using csv reader, iterate over the lines and filter them with the if statement.

Comment: @Boris I updated the code with the changes you mentioned earlier. How to do the other changes please?

Comment: If you want to process each file with a python function, use the `multiprocessing` module and pass it input and output file paths. You can also pass arguments specifying what columns and values to use for determining which output file to send the data to.

Comment: No, sorry, that's too broad of a question for this Q&A website. I would suggest initially _not_ doing multiprocessing — just write a function that given the needed arguments can split up one file the way you want. Then call it as the file tree is being walked. Once that is working, you can them use `multiprocessing` to run the conversions concurrently as a separate processes (if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

startdir = Path(".")
outputdir = startdir / "filtered"


def write_csv(filename, rows, fieldnames):
    # if there's nothing to write, don't write anything
    if not rows:
        return

    filename.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)


for input_filename in startdir.glob("**/*.csv"):
    with open(input_filename) as input_csv:
        inrows = []
        outrows = []

        reader = csv.DictReader(input_csv)
        for row in reader:
            if (
                row["Source address"] == "ac:37:43:9b:92:24"
                and row["Receiver address"] == "8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a"
            ):
                outrows.append(row)

            if (
                row["Transmitter address"] == "8c:15:c7:3a:d0:1a"
                and row["Destination address"] == "ac:37:43:9b:92:24"
            ):
                inrows.append(row)

        output_filename = outputdir / input_filename.relative_to(startdir)

        write_csv(output_filename.with_suffix(".out.csv"), outrows, reader.fieldnames)
        write_csv(output_filename.with_suffix(".in.csv"), inrows, reader.fieldnames)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the above code, I dont get any errors but no output as well. https://fil.email/zj9vgFo3 I have attached a sample csv file. sorry earlier i have just added as an image

Comment: @Hasa your rows are called "Destination address" and not "Destination" like in your screenshot/question. I've updated the code.

Comment: And also, the code should've been throwing up a `KeyError`. If you didn't see any errors, that probably means it's not finding any csv files. Do all your csv files end with `.csv`? Are you running this script from the directory that holds all your csv files or changing `startdir` to the path of that directory? It should at least work if you move the csv file to the same place as the script.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. Can I ask just one question. Here the output files (.in.csv and out.csv) gets written into the same place as original csv file. Would it be possible to save all the output files (both .in.csv and out.csv) into a different location/folder, having the same folder , sub folder names as original files. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're happy with this, please give me an updoot and mark as accepted. I work for imaginary internet points.

Comment: @Hasa cheers. I also work for real money. If you have more Python projects, my email is in my profile.

Comment: I will. and let my friends know as well.

Comment: just wondering you know how to do this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097740/split-csv-files-python-3-7

Comment: Thanks Boris. I got only this to do. Then I have to use weka tool. so no more coding after that.

Comment: I am a full time student. Its hard for me to afford. That's why I post on stackoverflow. I would be really great full if you can help only with this please. I won't ask for any more question. Only this please